# Usql with Azure Data Lake Store .net SDK

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-sdk-.net, u-sql

Can you please suggest can i use Usql with Azure Data Lake Store .net SDK.
Actually i need to upload some files to data lake store so i need to use Azure Data Lake Store SDK and i also need to add some record in Azure sql server database.
So i created a class library where i created a function to upload files to Data lake store as mentioned on below link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-net-sdk
Then i am calling this function by usql. But its not working fine and throwing error.
Can you please suggest is it actually possible or not or i need to use any other approach for the same.
Thanks

Comment: Since you have encountered the error, could you update your question and attach the detailed error message?

Comment: Hi i am facing following issue while calling sdk: 
Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.ScopeDebugException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.ScopeDebugException' occurred in Microsoft.Cosmos.ScopeStudio.BusinessObjects.Debugger.dll
Additional information: {"diagnosticCode":195887114,"severity":"Error","component":"RUNTIME","source":"User","err" while evaluating expression USQLApplication1.myFirstClass.myFirstFunction(EmpName)","description":"Inner exception from user expression: Method not found:

Answer (score 0):

The SDK is meant to be used from outside U-SQL, e.g., your client machine, or a VM outside of ADL, where the data lives that you want to upload.

If your files live inside ADLS already, [see the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44076102/1318169).

For more information why you cannot connect to web end points, [see this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888772/does-u-sql-allow-custom-code-to-call-external-services/41890492#41890492).