# Copy activity using USQL can any body share script

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Copy activity using U-SQL can any body share script

I want to read a file using copy activity using U-SQL and write this file on output in a file using U-SQL

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is the source file (Azure Blob Storage, Azure Data Lake, somewhere else)?  Copy Activity is an Azure Data Factory term, do you want to use that product?  it is possible.  This is the article on how to do it:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-usql-activity

Answer (score 0):

You can copy files in the following ways:

1. Azure Data Factory
2. [ADL Copy tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50358)
3. [Write a custom U-SQL extractor/outputter](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/FileCopyUDOs) (similar to 2)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a UDO that does that. The other samples are also quite useful.

https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/FileCopyUDOs