# Is it possible to send messages to an Azure Service Bus Queue or Event Hub from a U-SQL script?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azureservicebus, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

Is it possible for an Azure U-SQL script to put messages on an Azure Service Bus Queue or an Azure Event Hub? Please cite some documentation, if you can find it (since I can't find it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, this is not allowed.

A possible workaround would be to have the u-sql script output a file with messages to blob storage and have an azure function [pick those up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#trigger) and send them to an [Azure Service Bus Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#output) or an [Azure Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#output).

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b12001f-8684-48aa-a4a8-9f798e55d294/is-it-possible-to-send-an-external-http-request-or-messages-to-an-azure-service-bus-queue-from-a?forum=AzureDataLake).

> U-SQL scripts cannot access any external services, including Azure services such as web apps (with only a few exceptions like ADLS and WASB storage).  This is to prevent an unintended DDOS attack, since U-SQL will automatically scale that request across potentially hundreds or thousands of nodes, all running over potentially millions of rows and requesting simultaneously.  Please see Michael Rys' answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888772/does-u-sql-allow-custom-code-to-call-external-services) for more information.